which yuga does bali chakravarthi belong to?
Considering these facts,

Samudramantha happened in satyayuga and asura king bali was part of it
Vamana avatara happend in treta yuga and bali was punished

Did bali live across the yuga?

Who said you bali is killed? That's wrong info he is in pataloka and is not killed but punished by Vamana he will be the next indra.

true, my bad. Its also believed bali was the leader from dhaanav side in samudra manthan which happened in satya yuga, so is the confusion.

According to Vayu Purana, Bali lived during the 7th Tretya Yuga -

"In the seventh Tretayuga, the third incarnation happened to be of
Vamana (dwarf) when all the three worlds had been overrun by Daityas
and were ruled over by Bali.


Vayu Purana Chapter 98


Amazing. Thanks for the share.

Thanks,but its also believed bali was the leader from dhaanav side in samudra manthan which happened in satya yuga, so is the confusion.

@suresh Vamana Avatar is took place following the events of Samudra Manthan. So, it's possible that Samudra Manthan is happened at transtition of Satya to Treta Yuga.
